# tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename() function: How can I use it?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, opencv, explorer

So currently I'm reading images into my Python project with the `cv2.imread()` function, but it would be much cooler if I could go to my user interface, which I created with the `tkinter` module, and choose my picture from my Windows Explorer.

I found this function in Internet. If I use this my Windows explorer opens and I can select my picture, but nothing happens afterwards. I want save the picture in `img` but it doesnt work. Do you know what the problem is?

```
path = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(title='select', filetypes='.png')
img = cv2.imread(path, 1)
```

Comment: What do you _expect_ to happen afterwards?

Comment: i want to read it in and edit it and in the end i want show it the edited picture

Comment: So how do you know the code in your question doesn't work?

Comment: I have tested it. if i use this code then i can use my picture from my windows explorer and after that it hapepen nothing. I dont know how can i save my picture for editing

Comment: To _save_ an image, use [`tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/tkFileDialog.html).